# Tomcat unexpected maximum response time for a request when load testing is done using jmeter

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, embedded-tomcat

I have a spring boot application which has a post endpoint which takes the request and send it to another service and get the response back and save it to mongo database and returned the response back to user. The application is deployed on embedded tomcat of spring boot. I am using jmeter to see the max response time, throughput etc.

When i ran a test from jmeter with 500 threads for 10 minutes, i got maximum time as around 3500ms. 
When i repeat the test from jmeter the maximum time gets reduced to 900ms. 
Again, if i run the test after a long time, the maximum again goes upto 3500ms.

I am not able to get any information regarding this behavior of tomcat.

Could you please help me with understanding this behavior of tomcat?

Comment: I guess there is nothing to do with the tomcat. It's your application code. Check application logs and find out which operation is taking the time and why?.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "unexpected"? Lower response time when you repeat the test can be explained by either your application implementation, like when you start load test against the application which is just deployed it's performance might not be optimal and when you repeat the test the [cache is "warmed up"](https://www.section.io/blog/what-is-cache-warming/) so you're getting better performance.

Another explanation could be [JIT optimization](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html) as JVM is analyzing the pattern of your application usage and does inner improvements of the bytecode to better serve the given load pattern.

Third possible explanation is [MongoDB caching](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching), if 500 users are sending the same responses it might be the case the database stores the result sets in memory and when you repeat the test it doesn't actually access the storage but returns the results directly from the memory which is fast and cheap. Consider properly [parameterizing your JMeter test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide) so each thread (virtual user) would use its own credentials and perform different query than the other thread(s), but keep in mind that the test needs to be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability) so don't use unique data each time, it's better to have sufficient set of pre-defined test data